# Black color missing in Cmder/ConEmu with Git Bash

Tags: git, console, color-scheme, conemu, cmder

I'm using the latest preview of the [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) console emulator and the Git for Windows 2.20.1.

I followed the [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22481650/151641) question response where `git tree` aliases are presented and defined my variant of the alias in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
tree = log --all --graph --decorate=short --color --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) %C(auto)%d%C(reset)\n%x09%x09%x09%C(black)%s %C(reset)'
```

Basically, this renders commit message in black as it was faded away. It works well in the Git Bash console (right-hand side on the screenshot), while in the Cmder (left-hand side), the commit messages in black are not visible (of course, they are there, if I select the output):

[image]

*What tweaks to the colors would be required to make the left-hand side console look similar to the right-hand side?*

That is, to make the commit messages in black visible.

To be honest, I don't know if this is issue with Cmder or ConEmu configuration. I have tried all the color themes coming with Cmder, but without any improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you run the command in posix terminal, `black` is treated as rgb(0,0,0). But when you run git in WinAPI terminal, the output result is "color with **index 0**".

You may try [posix mode in ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinMsysConnector.html) too, but it's not so easy to setup for new users.

The simplest way:

1. change color of **index 0** to `0 0 0`

[image]

2. and change background color to appropriate value.

[image]

Comment: I confirm this works. One extra small step was required in my case: the "Placement" must be changed t "Stretch" (or "Tile"). Yes, even if the "Path" is just a color. Other  placements do not make the trick work. Thanks!